# How to avoid infinity loop when using useEffect() hooks when added dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, momentjs

I'm making a TimePicker like this

[image]

, I have another state is duration (number of hours from start to end), I made auto change end time when start or duration change function using useEffect().

It's work when I try to change the duration

but I'm got bug when I change start or end time
here is my code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setEnd(moment(start).add(duration, 'hours'));
    }, [start, duration]);
    useEffect(() => {
        setDuration(moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asHours());
    }, [end, start]);
```

[CodeSanBox Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/timepicker-oyp8m?file=/src/App.js) (it's difference with this question a bit, because I improved some logic about moment)

Update: Thanks for all your help, I did it, this is final code:
[CodeSanBox Final](https://codesandbox.io/s/timepicker-oyp8m?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is that you're modifying the thing that your `useEffect` hook depends on. If your hook is only supposed to run when `time` changes, then *don't change `time` in the hook or it will loop endlessly*.

Standard workaround if you do need a feedback loop but don't want it to be infinite have a boolean state that tells you whether or not to call `timeChange` inside your effect hook.

```
function Foo() {
  const [shouldUpdate, setShouldUpdate] = useState(false);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(...);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldUpdate) {
      setShouldUpdate(false);
      setTime(...);
    }
  }, [shouldUpdate, time]);
  return whatever;
}
```

Then `setShouldUpdate(true)` should be called by whatever actually triggers the state change.

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/timepicker-8mo3x?file=/src/App.js

Ok I think I got it; can likely be refactored even further, though it works:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TimePicker } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import moment from "moment";

const HHmm = "HH:mm";

export default function App() {
  const [time,setTime] = useState({
    start: "",
    end: "",
    duration: ""
  })
 
  const onStartChange = value => {
    if(time.start && time.end && time.duration) {
      const diffHours = value.diff(time.end, "hours");
      const diffMinutes = moment
        .utc(moment(value, HHmm).diff(moment(time.end, HHmm)))
        .format("mm");

      setTime((time)=>({
        start: value,
        end: time.end,
        duration: moment(`${diffHours} : ${diffMinutes}`, HHmm)
      }));
    } else {
      setTime((time)=>({
        start: value,
        end: time.end,
        duration: time.duration
      }))
    }

  };

  const onDurationChange = value => {
    if(time.start && time.end && time.duration) {
      const endToStartTime = moment(time.start)
          .add(value.hours(), "h")
          .add(value.minutes(), "m");

      setTime((time)=>({
        start: time.start,
        end: endToStartTime,
        duration: value
      }));
    } else {
      setTime((time)=>({
        start: time.start,
        end: time.end,
        duration: value
      }))
    }
    
  };

  const onEndChange = value => {
    if(time.start && time.end && time.duration) {
      const diffHours = value.diff(time.start, "hours");
      const diffMinutes = moment
        .utc(moment(value, HHmm).diff(moment(time.start, HHmm)))
        .format("mm");

      setTime((time)=>({
        start: time.start,
        end: value,
        duration: moment(`${diffHours} : ${diffMinutes}`, HHmm)
      }));
    } else {
      setTime((time)=>({
        start: time.start,
        end: value,
        duration: time.duration
      }))
    }
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
      if(time.start && time.end && !time.duration) {
        const diffHours = time.end.diff(time.start, "hours");
        const diffMinutes = moment
          .utc(moment(time.end, HHmm).diff(moment(time.start, HHmm)))
          .format("mm");
        setTime((time)=>({
          start: time.start,
          end: time.end,
          duration: moment(`${diffHours} : ${diffMinutes}`, HHmm)
        }));
      }

      if(time.start && !time.end && time.duration) {
        const endToStartTime = moment(time.start)
          .add(time.duration.hours(), "h")
          .add(time.duration.minutes(), "m");
        setTime((time)=>({
          start: time.start,
          end: endToStartTime,
          duration: time.duration
        }));
      }

      if(!time.start && time.end && time.duration) {
        const startToEndTime= moment(time.end)
          .subtract(time.duration.hours(), "h")
          .subtract(time.duration.minutes(), "m");
        setTime((time)=>({
          start: startToEndTime,
          end: time.end,
          duration: time.duration
        }));
      }
  },[time])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>Start: </span>
      <TimePicker value={time.start} onChange={onStartChange} format={HHmm} />
      <span>Duration: </span>
      <TimePicker value={time.duration} onChange={onDurationChange} format={HHmm} />
      <span>End: </span>
      <TimePicker value={time.end} onChange={onEndChange} format={HHmm} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: onChange doesn't work, I tried, setXXX will get the old value before it change

Comment: I updated my answer with another possible solution; can you provide the entire component code? That would help.

Comment: hmm, I tried but seem like it's doesn't work, I made an reproduce and add the link in the question, can you check it :D

Comment: Yeah I just realized theyre objects so they won't equate directly, but their ._i properties do. Still, the useEffect appears to be running continuously even when no changes are made. I'll open it up in vscode and take a look.

Comment: Take a look at my latest edit, I think I have a working version.